# Scrapy parser works bad

Tags: python, parsing, scrapy

The parser goes through all the names of pharmacies, but not all the names of medicines among pharmacies. Some pharmacies are loaded completely (more than 1000 lines), some only the first 20 lines (this is the number of lines on one page).

I think something is wrong with 'page medicines', 'page pharmacies' and resetting the counter. Also, the parser probably traverses some pages multiple times (duplicate DEBUG)

Perhaps I need to change the design of the code, put pagination in separate functions.

Could you help me with correction and redesign of my code?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
from ..items import AptekaItem
from urllib.request import Request
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from subprocess import call
from gc import callbacks
import sys

class AptSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'apt'
    allowed_domains = ['tabletka.by']
    #start_urls = ['https://tabletka.by/pharmacies?region=1006&page=1&sort=name&sorttype=asc']  # гродненская область
    start_urls = ['https://tabletka.by/pharmacies?region=38&page=1&sort=name&sorttype=asc']  # гродно
    page_pharmacies = 1 # номер страницы с аптеками
    page_medicines = 1 # номер страницы с лекарствами
    
    
    def parse(self, response):
        
        for row in (response.css("tbody tr")):
            # перебор по аптекам (на странице 20 штук)
            items = AptekaItem()
            name_of_pharmacy = row.css(".pharm-name .text-wrap a::text").get()
            location_of_pharmacy = row.css(".tooltip-info-header .text-wrap span::text").get()
            number_of_pharmacy = row.css(".phone.tooltip-info .tooltip-info-header .text-wrap a::text").get()
            
            items['name_of_pharmacy'] = name_of_pharmacy
            items['location_of_pharmacy'] = location_of_pharmacy
            items['number_of_pharmacy'] = number_of_pharmacy
            
            inner_link = urljoin('https://tabletka.by/', row.css(".pharm-name .text-wrap a::attr(href)").get())
            self.page_medicines = 1 # обнуление счетчика
            yield response.follow(inner_link, callback=self.parse_medicines, meta={'items' : items})
        
        # пагинация по аптекам
        while self.page_pharmacies < 10 and not response.css(".table-pagination.last-page"):
            #self.page_pharmacies += 1
            #yield response.follow('https://tabletka.by/pharmacies?region=1006&page=' + str(self.page_pharmacies) + '&sort=name&sorttype=asc', callback=self.parse)
            yield response.follow('https://tabletka.by/pharmacies?region=38&page=' + str(self.page_pharmacies) + '&sort=name&sorttype=asc', callback=self.parse)
            
            
    def parse_medicines(self, response):
        
        self.page_medicines = 1 # обнуление счетчика
        
        for low in response.css("tbody tr"):
            # перебор по названиям одной аптеки
            items = response.meta['items']
            name_of_medicine = low.css(".name.tooltip-info .tooltip-info-header a::text").get()
            
            # разделение на лекарства и остальное (разная структура так как у лекарств ссылка)
            a_or_t = low.css(".name.tooltip-info .capture::text").get().strip()
            if a_or_t:
                active_ingredient_or_type = a_or_t
            else:
                active_ingredient_or_type = low.css(".name.tooltip-info .capture a::text").get().strip()
            
            dosage_form = low.css(".form-title::text").get()
            prescribed = low.css(".form.tooltip-info .capture::text").get()
            name_of_manufacturer = low.css(".produce.tooltip-info .tooltip-info-header span a::text").get().strip()
            country_of_manufaturer = low.css(".produce.tooltip-info .capture::text").get().strip()
            price_of_medicine = low.css(".price-value::text").get().strip()
            
            items['name_of_medicine'] = name_of_medicine
            items['active_ingredient_or_type'] = active_ingredient_or_type
            items['dosage_form'] = dosage_form
            items['prescribed'] = prescribed
            items['name_of_manufacturer'] = name_of_manufacturer
            items['country_of_manufaturer'] = country_of_manufaturer
            items['price_of_medicine'] = price_of_medicine
            
            items['page'] = str(self.page_medicines)
            
            yield items
            
        # пагинация по лекарствам аптеки
        while self.page_medicines < 280 and not response.css(".table-pagination.last-page"):
            self.page_medicines += 1
            yield response.follow(response.urljoin('?page=') + str(self.page_medicines), callback = self.parse_medicines, meta=response.meta)
```

Setting file:

```
BOT_NAME = 'apteka'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['apteka.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'apteka.spiders'

USER_AGENT = "it's need for my studying project"

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, i solved it with for loop in "parse" function, works great.
maybe i can help someone

```
            for i in range(1, 240):
                inner_link = urljoin('https://tabletka.by/', (row.css(".pharm-name .text-wrap a::attr(href)").get() + '?page=' + str(i)))
                yield response.follow(inner_link, callback=self.parse_medicines, meta={'items' : items})
```

its all my code

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
from ..items import AptekaItem
from urllib.request import Request
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from subprocess import call
from gc import callbacks

class AptSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'apt'
    allowed_domains = ['tabletka.by']
    #start_urls = ['https://tabletka.by/pharmacies?region=1006&page=1&sort=name&sorttype=asc']  # гродненская область
    start_urls = ['https://tabletka.by/pharmacies?region=38&page=1&sort=name&sorttype=asc']  # гродно
    page_pharmacies = 1 # номер страницы с аптеками
    page_medicines = 1 # номер страницы с лекарствами
    
    def __init__(self, page_pharmacies=1, page_medicines=1, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AptSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.page_pharmacies = page_pharmacies
    
    def parse(self, response):
        
        for row in (response.css("tbody tr")):
            # перебор по аптекам (на странице 20 штук)
            items = AptekaItem()
            name_of_pharmacy = row.css(".pharm-name .text-wrap a::text").get()
            location_of_pharmacy = row.css(".tooltip-info-header .text-wrap span::text").get()
            number_of_pharmacy = row.css(".phone.tooltip-info .tooltip-info-header .text-wrap a::text").get()
            
            items['name_of_pharmacy'] = name_of_pharmacy
            items['location_of_pharmacy'] = location_of_pharmacy
            items['number_of_pharmacy'] = number_of_pharmacy
            
            for i in range(1, 240):
                inner_link = urljoin('https://tabletka.by/', (row.css(".pharm-name .text-wrap a::attr(href)").get() + '?page=' + str(i)))
                yield response.follow(inner_link, callback=self.parse_medicines, meta={'items' : items})

        # пагинация по аптекам
        if self.page_pharmacies < 10:  #and not response.css(".table-pagination.last-page")
            self.page_pharmacies += 1
            #yield response.follow('https://tabletka.by/pharmacies?region=1006&page=' + str(self.page_pharmacies) + '&sort=name&sorttype=asc', callback=self.parse)
            yield response.follow('https://tabletka.by/pharmacies?region=38&page=' + str(self.page_pharmacies) + '&sort=name&sorttype=asc', callback=self.parse)

            
    def parse_medicines(self, response):
        
        for low in response.css("tbody tr"):
            # перебор по названиям одной аптеки
            items = response.meta['items']
            name_of_medicine = low.css(".name.tooltip-info .tooltip-info-header a::text").get()
            
            # разделение на лекарства и остальное (разная структура так как у лекарств ссылка)
            a_or_t = low.css(".name.tooltip-info .capture::text").get().strip()
            if a_or_t:
                active_ingredient_or_type = a_or_t
            else:
                active_ingredient_or_type = low.css(".name.tooltip-info .capture a::text").get().strip()
            
            dosage_form = low.css(".form-title::text").get()
            prescribed = low.css(".form.tooltip-info .capture::text").get()
            name_of_manufacturer = low.css(".produce.tooltip-info .tooltip-info-header span a::text").get().strip()
            country_of_manufaturer = low.css(".produce.tooltip-info .capture::text").get().strip()
            price_of_medicine = low.css(".price-value::text").get().strip()
            
            items['name_of_medicine'] = name_of_medicine
            items['active_ingredient_or_type'] = active_ingredient_or_type
            items['dosage_form'] = dosage_form
            items['prescribed'] = prescribed
            items['name_of_manufacturer'] = name_of_manufacturer
            items['country_of_manufaturer'] = country_of_manufaturer
            items['price_of_medicine'] = price_of_medicine
            
            items['page'] = str(self.page_medicines)
            
            yield items
```